# Python, Getting stock data on particular days

Tags: python, pandas, stock, stocks

I'm looking into getting data from the American stock exchanges for some python code, Basically what I need to do is import a stock name and previous date in time and it will give me all the data for the next 10 days of the market being open, Is this possible?

```
market = input("Market:")
ticker = input("Ticker:")
ticker = ticker.upper()
ystartdate = (input("Start Date IN FORMAT yyyy-mm-dd:"))
day1=input("Day1 :")
day2=input("Day2 :")
day3=input("Day3 :")
day4=input("Day4 :")
day5=input("Day5 :")
day6=input("Day6 :")
day7=input("Day7 :")
day8=input("Day8 :")
day9=input("Day9 :")
day10=input("Day10:")
```

Currently i have to input all the data automatically but that is a pain to do, Basically i would put in a stock and date like 2012-10-15 and it would go look at the stock on that date and for the next 10 days. If its possible it would be a life saver! Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely shure where the stock data would come from. Do you just want to loop over multiple dates? That can be accomplised using either pandas or datetime, as pointed out by Alexis. Or are you trying to fetch the actual data from somewhere. Your question seems to imply the latter, but then you need to tell use where this "somewhere" is.

Comment: Pandas would be fine for it. i just need a way to input a ticker and it would auto set all the variables

Answer (score 0):

You should be working with a proper time format, not strings for this.

You can use pandas for example with datetime64.

```
import pandas as pd

input = ("Starting Date: ")
dates = pd.date_range(start=start_date, periods=10)
```

There is also the datetime package which has timedelta concepts which may help you if you don't want to use pandas.

Comment: How would i directly input this though into the day variables? and also add a ticker?

Answer (score 0):

I think what your need is included in pandas. In fact, you want to use either `pandas.bdate_range` or `pandas.date_range` with the `freq` argument set to `B` (I think both are more or less the same). These create *business days*, that is they would non include weekends. `bdate_range` also allows you to specify holidays, so I think that it might be a little more flexible.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> dates = pd.bdate_range(start='2018-10-25', periods=10)  # Start date is a Thursday
>>> print(dates)
DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-25', '2018-10-26', '2018-10-29', '2018-10-30',
           '2018-10-31', '2018-11-01', '2018-11-02', '2018-11-05',
           '2018-11-06', '2018-11-07'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')
```

Note how this excludes the 27th (a Saturday) and the 28th (a Sunday). If you want to specify holidays, you need to specify `freq='C'`.

Having these dates in separate variables is kind of ugly, but if you really want to, you can then go and unpack them like this:

```
>>> day1, day2, day3, day4, day5, day6, day7, day8, day9, day10 = dates
```